# Formality of: おXなされてくださりませ

Tags: politeness, formality

What nuance would be given by this pattern, example:

> お助けなされてくださりませ
>
> Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like pleading in a theatrical and archaic way. The same line is found in a historical play set in ancient China, published in 1925.

> （宮女一）もし、お助けなされてくださりませ。
> （張春）お身は誰ぢゃ。敵は已にうしろに迫った。ここらに迷うていては危いぞ。

https://dl.ndl.go.jp/pid/981972/1/113

Even as a theatrical phrase, the construction may be getting obsolete. お＿なされ and お＿くだされ are pretty much alive in the role language for historical play, though.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like someone is intentionally making a funny sentence by playing around with keigo. If you used it in a business setting, the listener would either laugh it off as a joke or feel offended.

- 助ける is closer to "rescue" rather than "lend a hand". It depends on the context, but unless you're really in danger (of losing your job, etc), the appropriate verb is 手伝う, 力を貸す, 助力する, etc.
- You are stacking honorific expressions too much, and くださりませ sounds like a samurai.

Answer (score -1):

I have to point out that くださる conjugates to くださいます, not くださります. All those honorific verbs are like that ござる, なさる, etc. So it's wrong in that sense anyway.

Comment: `it's wrong` -- でも青空文庫で検索すると、[「くださります」19件](https://myokoym.net/aozorasearch/search?word=%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99)、[「くださりませ」66件](https://myokoym.net/aozorasearch/search?word=%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B) ありますけど？

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. I don't know what the age or register of those examples is, but surely that's not modern, colloquial Japanese? お約束してくださりまするか, for example? I can find 'holp' as the past participle of 'to help' in Shakespeare, but I don't tell people learning English that it's the correct form today. Is there any textbook on modern, colloquial Japanese that lists くださります as a valid option here? That would be interesting to see.

Comment: As Japanese, くださります is more understandable and more current than English _holp_. Plus, the questioner already used this form, which is valid (albeit archaic) Japanese, and is asking for details about the nuance and how it comes across.  Just saying _"it's wrong"_, when it clearly isn't, does not a helpful post make. 

Comment: Granted, I was at fault. I was unfamiliar with it.